# Will localstorage be reset when webview is updated to mobile app?

Tags: android, web, webview, local-storage, updates

I have a mobile app that uses webview. I keep the userid variable in the localstorage value on this website, will the localstorage values be reset when I make a new update to the application?

This code is have;

```
webView.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

what can i do against it

Comment: As long as it's an update and not an uninstall and reinstall, it should be fine.  Updates do not delete local files.